# Sort Versions in Python

Tags: python, sorting, distutils

I'm trying to get it so that 1.7.0 comes after 1.7.0.rc0 but before 1.8.0, as it should if you were sorting versions. I thought the whole point of LooseVersion was that it handled the sorting and comparison of this kind of thing correctly.

```
>>> from distutils.version import LooseVersion
>>> versions = ["1.7.0", "1.7.0.rc0", "1.8.0"]
>>> lv = [LooseVersion(v) for v in versions]
>>> sorted(lv, reverse=True)
[LooseVersion ('1.8.0'), LooseVersion ('1.7.0.rc0'), LooseVersion ('1.7.0')]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**MAJOR EDIT:** old answer was too unpythonic. Here are two prettier solutions.

So, I currently see about three ways of achieving the wished ordering, releases candidates "rc" before actual releases.

1. my old, imperative-style ordering
2. use "b" instead of "rc" in order to use `StrictVersion`, from the same package
3. extend the `Version` class to add support for arbitrary tags and tag ordering

### 1. Old, imperative-style ordering

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
versions = ["1.7.0", "1.7.0.rc0", "1.8.0"]
lv = [LooseVersion(v) for v in versions]
lv.sort()

sorted_rc = [v.vstring for v in lv]

import re
p = re.compile('rc\\d+$')

i = 0

# skip the first RCs
while i + 1 < len(sorted_rc):
    m = p.search(sorted_rc[i])
    if m:
        i += 1
    else:
        break

while i + 1 < len(sorted_rc):
    tmp = sorted_rc[i]
    m = p.search(sorted_rc[i+1])
    if m and sorted_rc[i+1].startswith(tmp):
        sorted_rc[i] = sorted_rc[i+1]
        sorted_rc[i+1] = tmp
    i += 1
```

with this I get:

```
['1.7.0rc0', '1.7.0', '1.11.0']
```

### 2. Use "b" instead of "rc"

The package `distutils.version` also has another class, `StrictVersion` which does the job, if your `1.7.0.rc0` is allowed to be written as `1.7.0a0` or `1.7.0b0` noting alpha or beta releases.

That is:

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
versions = ["1.7.0", "1.7.0b0", "1.11.0"]
sorted(versions, key=StrictVersion)
```

This gives:

```
['1.7.0b0', '1.7.0', '1.11.0']
```

Translation from one form to another can be done using the [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) module.

### 3. Extend the Version class

The obvious problem of the previous solution is the lack of flexibility of `StrictVersion`. Altering the `version_re` class attribute to use `rc` instead of `a` or `b`, even if it accepts `1.7.1rc0`, still prints it as `1.7.1r0` (as of python 2.7.3).

We can get it right by implementing our own custom version class. This can be done like this, with some unit tests to ensure correctness at least in some cases:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# file: version2.py

from distutils import version
import re
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class NumberedVersion(version.Version):
    """
    A more flexible implementation of distutils.version.StrictVersion

    This implementation allows to specify:
    - an arbitrary number of version numbers:
        not only '1.2.3' , but also '1.2.3.4.5'
    - the separator between version numbers:
        '1-2-3' is allowed when '-' is specified as separator
    - an arbitrary ordering of pre-release tags:
        1.1alpha3 < 1.1beta2 < 1.1rc1 < 1.1
        when ["alpha", "beta", "rc"] is specified as pre-release tag list
    """

    def __init__(self, vstring=None, sep='.', prerel_tags=('a', 'b')):
        version.Version.__init__(self) 
            # super() is better here, but Version is an old-style class

        self.sep = sep
        self.prerel_tags = dict(zip(prerel_tags, xrange(len(prerel_tags))))
        self.version_re = self._compile_pattern(sep, self.prerel_tags.keys())
        self.sep_re = re.compile(re.escape(sep))

        if vstring:
            self.parse(vstring)


    _re_prerel_tag = 'rel_tag'
    _re_prerel_num = 'tag_num'

    def _compile_pattern(self, sep, prerel_tags):
        sep = re.escape(sep)
        tags = '|'.join(re.escape(tag) for tag in prerel_tags)

        if tags:
            release_re = '(?:(?P<{tn}>{tags})(?P<{nn}>\d+))?'\
                .format(tags=tags, tn=self._re_prerel_tag, nn=self._re_prerel_num)
        else:
            release_re = ''

        return re.compile(r'^(\d+)(?:{sep}(\d+))*{rel}$'\
            .format(sep=sep, rel=release_re))

    def parse(self, vstring):
        m = self.version_re.match(vstring)
        if not m:
            raise ValueError("invalid version number '{}'".format(vstring))

        tag = m.group(self._re_prerel_tag)
        tag_num = m.group(self._re_prerel_num)

        if tag is not None and tag_num is not None:
            self.prerelease = (tag, int(tag_num))
            vnum_string = vstring[:-(len(tag) + len(tag_num))]
        else:
            self.prerelease = None
            vnum_string = vstring

        self.version = tuple(map(int, self.sep_re.split(vnum_string)))


    def __repr__(self):
        return "{cls} ('{vstring}', '{sep}', {prerel_tags})"\
            .format(cls=self.__class__.__name__, vstring=str(self),
                sep=self.sep, prerel_tags = list(self.prerel_tags.keys()))

    def __str__(self):
        s = self.sep.join(map(str,self.version))
        if self.prerelease:
            return s + "{}{}".format(*self.prerelease)
        else:
            return s

    def __lt__(self, other):
        """
        Fails when  the separator is not the same or when the pre-release tags
        are not the same or do not respect the same order.
        """
        # TODO deal with trailing zeroes: e.g. "1.2.0" == "1.2"
        if self.prerel_tags != other.prerel_tags or self.sep != other.sep:
            raise ValueError("Unable to compare: instances have different"
                " structures")

        if self.version == other.version and self.prerelease is not None and\
                other.prerelease is not None:

            tag_index = self.prerel_tags[self.prerelease[0]]
            other_index = self.prerel_tags[other.prerelease[0]]
            if tag_index == other_index:
                return self.prerelease[1] < other.prerelease[1]

            return tag_index < other_index

        elif self.version == other.version:
            return self.prerelease is not None and other.prerelease is None

        return self.version < other.version

    def __eq__(self, other):
        tag_index = self.prerel_tags[self.prerelease[0]]
        other_index = other.prerel_tags[other.prerelease[0]]
        return self.prerel_tags == other.prerel_tags and self.sep == other.sep\
            and self.version == other.version and tag_index == other_index and\
                self.prerelease[1] == other.prerelease[1]




import unittest

class TestNumberedVersion(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.v = NumberedVersion()

    def test_compile_pattern(self):
        p = self.v._compile_pattern('.', ['a', 'b'])
        tests = {'1.2.3': True, '1a0': True, '1': True, '1.2.3.4a5': True,
            'b': False, '1c0': False, ' 1': False, '': False}
        for test, result in tests.iteritems():
            self.assertEqual(result, p.match(test) is not None, \
                "test: {} result: {}".format(test, result))


    def test_parse(self):
        tests = {"1.2.3.4a5": ((1, 2, 3, 4), ('a', 5))}
        for test, result in tests.iteritems():
            self.v.parse(test)
            self.assertEqual(result, (self.v.version, self.v.prerelease))

    def test_str(self):
        tests = (('1.2.3',), ('10-2-42rc12', '-', ['rc']))
        for t in tests:
            self.assertEqual(t[0], str(NumberedVersion(*t)))

    def test_repr(self):
        v = NumberedVersion('1,2,3rc4', ',', ['lol', 'rc'])
        expected = "NumberedVersion ('1,2,3rc4', ',', ['lol', 'rc'])"
        self.assertEqual(expected, repr(v))


    def test_order(self):
        test = ["1.7.0", "1.7.0rc0", "1.11.0"]
        expected = ['1.7.0rc0', '1.7.0', '1.11.0']
        versions = [NumberedVersion(v, '.', ['rc']) for v in test]
        self.assertEqual(expected, list(map(str,sorted(versions))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

So, it can be used like this:

```
import version2
versions = ["1.7.0", "1.7.0rc2", "1.7.0rc1", "1.7.1", "1.11.0"]
sorted(versions, key=lambda v: version2.NumberedVersion(v, '.', ['rc']))
```

output:

```
['1.7.0rc1', '1.7.0rc2', '1.7.0', '1.7.1', '1.11.0']
```

So, in conclusion, use python's included batteries or roll out your own.

About this implementation: it could be improved by dealing with the trailing zeroes in the releases, and memoize the compilation of the regular expressions.

Comment: It's still wrong, 1.7.0.rc0 did not come in between version 1.7.0 and 1.11.0 -- 1.7.0.rc0 is the release candidate for 1.7.0 therefore it should come before 1.7.0

Comment: Ok, so you don't want [lexical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_order)

Comment: Right and that is exactly what pep 386 says it should handle: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/

Comment: @TylerBrock: your original question says that 1.7.0 should come first.

Comment: I like your answer, but was hoping for something cleaner. Thanks Bernard.

Comment: hum... it is still not completely right. I upload the code for the corrected version

Answer (score 21):

```
>>> from distutils.version import LooseVersion
>>> versions = ["1.7.0", "1.7.0rc0", "1.11.0"]
>>> sorted(versions, key=LooseVersion)
['1.7.0', '1.7.0rc0', '1.11.0']
```

from the docs

> Version numbering for anarchists and software realists. Implements the
>   standard interface for version number classes as described above.  A
>   version number consists of a series of numbers, separated by either
>   periods or strings of letters.  When comparing version numbers, the
>   numeric components will be compared numerically, and the alphabetic
>   components lexically.
>   ...
>   In fact, there is no such thing as an invalid version number under
>   this scheme; the rules for comparison are simple and predictable, but
>   may not always give the results you want (for some definition of
>   "want").

so you see there is no smarts about treating "rc" specially

You can see how the version number is broken down like this

```
>>> LooseVersion('1.7.0rc0').version
[1, 7, 0, 'rc', 0]
```

Comment: 1.11 > 1.7, you've got them around the wrong way. But yes, the other information is useful.

Comment: I had read that, and while I understand numeric components are compared numerically and alphabetic are compare lexically, doesn't the fact that there is an alphabetical component contribute to it being sorted as coming before the one without alphabetical component. If not, it should, because alpha, beta, rc, etc... all come before versions without those additional alphabetic components.

Comment: Yep, i understood all this. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I just wanted to point out your code does exactly the same thing as mine, I just map LooseVersion beforehand.

Comment: I think this is not working. Would expect this order as the correct result `['1.11.0', '1.7.0', '1.7.0rc0']`

Answer (score 10):

I found this to be helpful and a bit simpler:

```
from packaging import version

vers = ["1.7.0", "1.7.0rc2", "1.7.0rc1", "1.7.1", "1.11.0"]

sorted(vers, key=lambda x: version.Version(x))
```

Which results in:

```
['1.7.0rc1', '1.7.0rc2', '1.7.0', '1.7.1', '1.11.0']
```

Adding `reverse=True` puts them in "descending" order which I find helpful.

```
['1.11.0', '1.7.1', '1.7.0', '1.7.0rc2', '1.7.0rc1']
```

It can sort a pretty wide variety of version-style numbers (my testbed was Linux versions v4.11.16, etc)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. My issue was I had versions with only one decimal, and so the latest version was resulting in "2.9.1" when 2.10 had been in the list. Ref: Infoblox api schema version sorting

Comment: thanks now i don't get the warnings from using from distutils.version import StrictVersion versions.sort(key=StrictVersion)       (even do i think is easier syntax.)

Comment: You can use `key=version.Version` instead of `key=lambda x: version.Version(x)`

Answer (score 7):

I use the [pkg_resources](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0365/) module like so:

```
from pkg_resources import parse_version

def test_version_sorting():
    expected = ['1.0.0dev0',
                '1.0.0dev1',
                '1.0.0dev2',
                '1.0.0dev10',
                '1.0.0rc0',
                '1.0.0rc2',
                '1.0.0rc5',
                '1.0.0rc21',
                '1.0.0',
                '1.1.0',
                '1.1.1',
                '1.1.11',
                '1.2.0',
                '1.3.0',
                '1.23.0',
                '2.0.0', ]
    alphabetical = sorted(expected)
    shuffled = sorted(expected, key=lambda x: random())
    assert expected == sorted(alphabetical, key=parse_version)
    assert expected == sorted(shuffled, key=parse_version)
```

Note that creating a random ordering from the expected version list makes this a potentially unstable unit test as two runs will not have the same data. Still, in this instance, it should not matter… Hopefully.

Comment: So easy and beautiful, I'll go with it

Comment: `>>> from pkg_resources import parse_version
>>> list = ['0.00.1', '0.00.2', '0.00.3', '0.00.10']
>>> sorted(list)
['0.00.1', '0.00.10', '0.00.2', '0.00.3']`

Doesn't sort this case as expected however

Comment: @Brendan I am no longer contributing to SE as long as they continue to abuse their users.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

def sort_software_versions(versions = [], reverse = False):
  def split_version(version):
    def toint(x):
      try:
        return int(x)
      except:
        return x
    return map(toint, re.sub(r'([a-z])([0-9])', r'\1.\2', re.sub(r'([0-9])([a-z])', r'\1.\2', version.lower().replace('-', '.'))).split('.'))
  def compare_version_list(l1, l2):
    def compare_version(v1, v2):
      if isinstance(v1, int):
        if isinstance(v2, int):
          return v1 - v2
        else:
          return 1
      else:
        if isinstance(v2, int):
          return -1
        else:
          return cmp(v1, v2)
    ret = 0
    n1 = len(l1)
    n2 = len(l2)
    if n1 < n2:
      l1.extend([0]*(n2 - n1))
    if n2 < n1:
      l2.extend([0]*(n1 - n2))
    n = max(n1, n2)
    i = 0
    while not ret and i < n:
      ret = compare_version(l1[i], l2[i])
      i += 1
    return ret
  return sorted(versions, cmp = compare_version_list, key = split_version, reverse = reverse)
```

---

```
print(sort_software_versions(['1.7.0', '1.7.0.rc0', '1.8.0']))
['1.7.0.rc0', '1.7.0', '1.8.0']
```

This way it handles alpha, beta, rc correctly. It can deal with versions containing hyphens, or when people glued the 'rc' to the version.
The re.sub can use compiled regexp, but this works ok enough.

Comment: Buddy, what is the licence of this snippet of code ? ;-)

Comment: MIT or BSD or WTF licence.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to use ".devX" as the "prerelease" identifier, so here's another implementation, largely based on `distutils.version.StrictVersion`

```py
class ArtefactVersion(Version):
    """
    Based on distutils/version.py:StrictVersion
    """
    version_re = re.compile(r'^(\d+) \. (\d+) \. (\d+) (\.dev\d+)?$', re.VERBOSE | re.ASCII)

    def parse(self, vstring):
        match = self.version_re.match(vstring)
        if not match:
            raise ValueError("invalid version number '%s'" % vstring)

        (major, minor, patch, prerelease) = match.group(1, 2, 3, 4)

        self.version = tuple(map(int, [major, minor, patch]))
        if prerelease:
            self.prerelease = prerelease[4:]
        else:
            self.prerelease = None

    def __str__(self):
        vstring = '.'.join(map(str, self.version))

        if self.prerelease:
            vstring = vstring + f".dev{str(self.prerelease)}"

        return vstring

    def _cmp(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            other = ArtefactVersion(other)

        if self.version != other.version:
            # numeric versions don't match
            # prerelease stuff doesn't matter
            if self.version < other.version:
                return -1
            else:
                return 1

        # have to compare prerelease
        # case 1: neither has prerelease; they're equal
        # case 2: self has prerelease, other doesn't; other is greater
        # case 3: self doesn't have prerelease, other does: self is greater
        # case 4: both have prerelease: must compare them!

        if (not self.prerelease and not other.prerelease):
            return 0
        elif (self.prerelease and not other.prerelease):
            return -1
        elif (not self.prerelease and other.prerelease):
            return 1
        elif (self.prerelease and other.prerelease):
            if self.prerelease == other.prerelease:
                return 0
            elif self.prerelease < other.prerelease:
                return -1
            else:
                return 1
        else:
            assert False, "never get here"
```

Answer (score 0):

If versions are adherent to the [SemVer](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) specification, I suggest to use the  [semver python module](https://github.com/python-semver/python-semver).

This module is specifically developed to handle semantic version format and proper comparisons - essential for sorting.

```
>>> import semver
>>> versions = ["1.7.0", "1.7.0-rc0", "1.8.0"]
>>> sorted(versions, reverse=True, key=lambda v: semver.VersionInfo.parse(v))

['1.8.0', '1.7.0', '1.7.0-rc0']
```